# stress testing concurrency: how to slow down thread execution oin my application?

Tags: debugging, concurrency, emulation

I have hit situations where certain race conditions only occur when I run my application in the valgrind emulator. But if I run my executable as a normal program these issues did not occur.

My theory is that the emulator slows down execution so much that threads have larger common time frames in which they execute and can operate on shared data structures thereby increasing the chance of hitting race conditions on these shared resources.

I would like to have a more fine grained control on e.g. a virtual clock frequency by means of a specialized emulator.

Does somebody know about an existing tool to do this job. I have tried to search for this online. There should be some academic paper dealing with this. But so far I haven't found it yet.

Comment: Re, "virtual clock frequency." You won't change the behavior of your program by uniformly slowing _everything_ down. If changing the timing makes any difference it's because you changed the _relative_ timing of different threads.

Comment: What you're looking for is called systematic concurrency testing. This type of testing "takes control" of the thread interleavings and exhaustively checks different combinations that may lead to undesirable race conditions.

Comment: @SolomonSlow yes, you are right! a uniform slow down of execution is not warranted indeed. I think I need to define and slow down the critical sections only.